# How to redirect after sf_method 'delete'?

Tags: php, symfony-1.4

Backend with admin-generator in edit form I output the list of related objects, which is to remove the

```
link_to ('delete', $rel_object-> name. '_delete', 
           Array ('id' => $rel_object-> id), 
          array ('method '=>' delete ',' confirm '=>' You are serious? ',)
```

press to delete the related object, but is redirected to a list of related objects, and I need to do a redirect back to the edit form of the object.

Comment: Modify it where it does the current redirect?

Comment: I do not know where it redirects, no thought how to do it

Comment: This seems to be some specific, how do you list *related objects*? Is it a custom action?

Comment: This happens in the custom widget

Comment: handed over the keys to the model on which the associated object model forms and related models. Then they make a request in the doctrine cycle make out objects and output the

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your delete request is being answered and dealt with by a controller action - you need to check your routing to see which.

My executeDelete action is as follows

```
public function executeDelete(sfWebRequest $request)
{
    // delete the associated object
    $request->checkCSRFProtection();
    $this->forward404Unless($model= Doctrine_Core::getTable('model')->find(array($request->getParameter('id'))), sprintf('Object does not exist (%s).', $request->getParameter('id')));
    $model->delete();

    // change this line
    $this->redirect('model/index');
}
```

You need to change `$this->redirect('model/index');` to be wherever you want to redirect to

Comment: ManseUK you are Master! Thank you very much
It helped. Share my results. 

UPDATE I used to return here this code

$this->redirect($request->getReferer());